# how to remove child object from the parent object list, java

Tags: java, algorithm, list, recursion, arraylist

for examplethere is array list that contain  4 objects. ex:  object 1, object2 , child1_object1 ,child1_object1. Inside the object 1 contain  child1_object1 ,child1_object1 as follows

[image]
inside

Now i want algorithm to remove child object from main list. please help

Comment: _i want_ is a wish not a question. Please read Help Center and ask specific question with your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure look like a **Map**, one mapping object to List.
**See Guava MultiMap here**
https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html

If you don't want a dependency, you can do something like this:

```
int parentIndex = parentList.indexOf(parentObject);
if(parentIndex != -1){
   List<Object> children = parentList.get(parentIndex);
   if(children != null){
     children.remove(childIndex);
   }
 }
```

However, I recommend you use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to point to children.

```
parentList.indexOf(parentObject);
```

does  a linear search which is O(n), as it may be a problem if your parent list is very large.